# Spark Local gets better performance than Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-spark, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm currently using Spark with DataFrames to make a series of HTTP GET requests for each Row. I'm currently using the Apache HttpClient 4.5.x dependency to make the GET requests. I've noticed that when I run in local mode (`--master local[256]`), I'm able to get a fairly large amount of GETs/second (approximately 100/s). However, (unsurprisingly), when I try to scale past 256 local driver threads, performance starts to degrade. I'm able to run 256 local threads on my 4-core laptop due to the long IO blocking from HttpClient.

I then switched over to a 5-worker-node Spark cluster on AWS EMR (with each worker node having twice as many cores as my laptop), hoping to emulate the emulate the same 256-threads-per-worker-node setup to try and get 5x the throughput. `spark-submit` fails to start when I set the `--executor-cores` setting to a number higher than the available vCores reported by YARN.

Is there a way to easily replicate the local[256] behavior on 5 workers to get an approximate 5x increase in throughput?

I've tried a few options with sub-par results.

1. I've tried setting up a Dockerized Spark Standalone cluster and updated the SPARK_WORKER_CORES to a very high number with limited success. Although I'm now able to spin-up 128 threads per worker, performance is dismal. It's been a few hours since trying it so I can't remember if there was a large amount of shuffle happening or not.
2. I've updated my code to implement [the asynchronous sliding window pattern](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/02/27/Concurrency-In-Spark/). This was an amazing article that looked promising, but even with the 5-worker-node set-up, I'm still not able to perform as many GETs as `local[256]` (although it's close). Side note: the post explains an updated "sliding iterator" that I was not able to convert over (he's since changed his code to use a Google-provided Futures library, and I was trying to stick to the scala.concurrent version).
3. I've tried using the Apache HttpAsyncClient 4.1.x library as well but it did not seem to make much of a difference.

This is the current code-base that was written for the 5-worker-node setup. The `local[256]` set-up does a naive `df.map(row => getRow(row)`

```scala
package com.me.bot

import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, TimeUnit}

import org.apache.http.client.methods.{CloseableHttpResponse, HttpGet}
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}

object Bot {
  val MaxConcurrency: Int = 128

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Bot").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("/path/to/urls.csv")
    df.rdd.
      map(row => ThreadedConcurrentContext.executeAsync(getRow(row))).
      mapPartitions(it => ThreadedConcurrentContext.awaitSliding(it, MaxConcurrency)).
      toDF().write.mode("append").parquet("/path/to/output")

    spark.stop()
  }

  def getRow(row: Row) = {
    val url = row.getAs[String]("url")
    GetResult(Browser.getStatusCode(url), url)
  }
}

case class GetResult(statusCode: Int, url: String)

object Browser extends Serializable {
  lazy val cm = {
    val manager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()
    manager.setMaxTotal(Bot.MaxConcurrency)
    manager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(Bot.MaxConcurrency)
    manager
  }

  lazy val httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(cm).setConnectionTimeToLive(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()

  val context = new ThreadLocal[HttpClientContext] {
    override def initialValue = HttpClientContext.create()
  }

  def getStatusCode(url: String) = {
    var response: CloseableHttpResponse = null

    try {
      val httpget = new HttpGet(url)
      response = httpClient.execute(httpget, context.get())
      response.getStatusLine.getStatusCode
    }
    catch {
      case ex: Exception => -1
      case _: Throwable => -1
    }
    // soooo not Scala... sorry!
    finally {
      if (response != null) {
        response.close()
      }
    }
  }
}

// From http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/02/27/Concurrency-In-Spark/
/** A singleton object that controls the parallelism on a Single Executor JVM */
object ThreadedConcurrentContext {
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
  import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration._

  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newWorkStealingPool(Bot.MaxConcurrency))

  /** Wraps a code block in a Future and returns the future */
  def executeAsync[T](f: => T): Future[T] = Future(f)

  /** Awaits only a set of elements at a time. Instead of waiting for the entire batch
    * to finish waits only for the head element before requesting the next future*/
  def awaitSliding[T](it: Iterator[Future[T]], batchSize: Int, timeout: Duration = Inf): Iterator[T] = {
    val slidingIterator = it.sliding(batchSize - 1) //Our look ahead (hasNext) will auto start the nth future in the batch
    val (initIterator, tailIterator) = slidingIterator.span(_ => slidingIterator.hasNext)
    initIterator.map( futureBatch => Await.result(futureBatch.head, timeout)) ++
      tailIterator.flatMap( lastBatch => Await.result(Future.sequence(lastBatch), timeout))
  }

  def awaitAll[T](it: Iterator[Future[T]], timeout: Duration = Inf) = {
    Await.result(Future.sequence(it), timeout)
  }
}
```

I would like to get in the ballpark of 5x throughput using 5 worker nodes. I don't have plans to scale much beyond that as my webserver probably can't handle much more.